# Is it secure to store SecretKey in app memory during runtime

Tags: android, security, encryption

I use AES to encrypt cached data returned from server and user password. During the main flow I initialize KeyStore and store SecureKey there, retrieving it before sending a request to server (to decrypt password) and before loading cached response (if needed).

However, I'd like to give users an option not to initialize KeyStore if they don't want to. In this case user must log in to the application manually each time. A new SecureKey will be generated each time and stored in application memory until it is running or in background.

My question: is it secure enough to store once obtained SecureKey in app's memory (note: not hardcoded at build time), since the application may be running for several days?

Comment: Passwords should be hashed, not encrypted.

Comment: But the problem is server accepts only plain password in HTTP request header. It's not configured for session tokens.

Comment: surely you should be storing the hash + salt of the password on the server and parsing the password value to a function that returns a boolean of after checking the hash. I would advise against storing anything sensitive on the client side, let the server do all that as a client can easily be reverse engineered and root users can get to the data/data folder.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "safe"?

If an opponent gets access to a device on which your application is running, freezes it, disassembles it, and examines the memory, they can find the password.

If your application is running on a device with a compromised kernel, the in-memory password is completely vulnerable.

If your application includes a library from a 3rd party advertising agency, the in-memory password is toast.

If none of these are attacks that concerns you, then you are probably ok.